# Popping to first view controller of the project

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController`. I load a `presentmodalviewcontroller` over it. And I push 2 more view controllers over the `presentmodalviewcontroller`. If I need to move to my first view controller, what should be done?

Edit: I am also loading some `UIView` over the `UIViewController` on top of my stack. I have successfully removed that.

I have tried

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers   objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

but still its not working

This is how I am adding each view controller

First viewcontroller

```
 FirstViewController *firstViewController = 
 [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

 UINavigationController *navcontrol =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
 [self presentModalViewController:navcontrol animated:YES];
 [navcontrol release];
```

Second viewcontroller

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]init] ;
[self.navigationController pushViewController: secondViewController animated:YES];
        [secondViewController release];
```

Third viewcontroller

```
ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: thirdViewController animated:YES];
[thirdViewController release];
```

Comment: Would you facepalm if I said the answer was -popToRootViewController:animated?

Comment: I have tried 
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];

but still its not working

Comment: Why not you tried to push to your firstViewController instead of doing this?

Comment: I don't want to create a new instance

Comment: Can you show your code of how you are placing your viewControllers on the nav stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got it.

```
    myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    [appDelegate.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```